# How to measure the noise in gradients of deep neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient

I'm dealing with a problem related to explainable AI. The short version of the issue I have is that I've observed some interesting differences between large and small BERT models and I suspect that noisy gradients are the cause. I know gradients are noisy - Integrated Gradients and SmoothGRAD address the saturation and local instability issues. The problem I have is that I don't know if large models (bert-base-cased) have more noise in their gradients compared to small models (14M parameter BERT model).

I'm looking for a way to measure the amount of noise the gradients contain. I tried to find articles that deal with this issue but I didn't find any. Something that's theoretically sound would be great, but at this point, I'm thankful for any ideas.

Comment: the noise depends on the dataset your are working on... if you have a single sample, the variance is zero singe SGD decays to GD... if you have big dataset where you use  stochastic optimizers, you have a lot of variable to consider... it depends on the optimizer, it depends on the initialization, it depends on the regularization, it depends on the local minima you end up on

Comment: if you have enough resources, take the gradient wrt the full dataset, and that's the exact gradient, than take some minibatches, and calculate the distance of the gradients produced by them and the exact gradient, and you will estimate $Var(\nabla|\theta)$, however you ideally should fo that over the distribution of $\theta$... which is kinda hard to approximate